# Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n -1}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Does $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^n -1}$$ converge or diverge?

The tests I know so far are: by **defintion, geometric, divergence, integral**.

The only appealing method right now is the integral test, but the it looks hard to integrate. Any suggestions? I don't see how I can rewrite this in an equivalent form.

Comment: Similar to your other question: Comparison test is a strong tool. Also, the series should start from $n=2$ shouldn't it?

Comment: My question says 1

Comment: It is less than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n-2^{n-1}} = \sum \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ which is geometric.

Comment: Ah yes, nvm. The start of a series is not that important to its convergency.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978329/44121

Comment: The posed question is completely trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the integral test, which was what you thought was the way to go.

We consider $$I=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^x -1 } \ dx.$$

Multiply top and bottom of integrand with $2^{-x}$ so that

$$I=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-x}}{1 -2^{-x} } \ dx.$$

Let $u=1-2^{-x}.$ Then $du = 2^{-x} \ln(2) \ dx.$

So $$I= \int_{\frac{1}{2}} ^{1} \frac{1}{\ln(2) u} \ du = \frac{\ln(1)-\ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)}{\ln(2)}= \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(2)}=1.$$ So the integral converges, and so the sum in question converges too.

Answer (score 2):

For all $n\ge 1$ we have $2^{n-1}+1\le 2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}=2^n$, thus $$2^{n-1}\le 2^n-1\iff \frac{1}{2^n-1}\le\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Then we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n-1}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=2,$$
which implies that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n-1}}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Compare $2^n-1$ to $n^\frac98$, which is smaller for all $n>1$. This means $\sum_0^\infty n^{-\frac98} > \sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{2^n-1}$ for all $n>1$. Since $\frac{1}{2^n-1}$ with $n=1$,  and $\sum_0^\infty n^{-\frac98}$ is convergent (by the integral test), we know that since $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{2^n-1}$ is bigger for all $n>1$, it must be convergent too.

Comment: How are you going to prove the first assertion?

Comment: Induction, I'm guessing.