# How can I solve the infinite series 1+1/3+1/7+1/15+1/31+1/63+...

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the summation of this infinite series
$$1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{31} + \frac{1}{63} + ... ?$$

Comment: A starting point is to find the lower bound and upper bound. What does the limiting value of the infinite sum $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}$ tell you?

Comment: It has no closed form without using 'special' functions like digamma, but it's a well-known constant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Borwein_constant

Comment: The sum of the receiprocals of mersenne numbers. That's what I am looking for. But is there an exact value other than an approximate value?

Comment: On @StevenStadnicki 's Wikipedia page it mentions that Erdos proved that the number is irrational. The OEIS page (https://oeis.org/A065442) does not mention if it is transcendental.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if transcendentality is provable by showing that it's too well-approximable.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: here (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978329/44121) I showed a series acceleration technique that should easily lead to the trascendentality of such constant.