# $\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{99} + \frac{1}{999} + \frac{1}{9999} + \cdots ={} $?

Tags: summation

Sum the following:
\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{99} + \frac{1}{999} + \frac{1}{9999} + \cdots\\[0.1in]
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{10}^n - 1}
\end{align}

It's fairly straightforward to show that this sum converges:
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{10}^n - 1}\\
&= \frac{1}{9} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{10}^n - 1}\\
&< \frac{1}{9} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{10}^n - 10}\\
&= \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{10}^{n-1} - 1}\\
&= \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10}S\, ,
\end{align}
which leads to $S < 10/81 = 0.\overline{123456790}$.

Numerically (Mathematica), we find that this sum is approximately $S \approx 0.122324$.

This sum can also be written as
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{10}^n - 1}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1/{10}^n}{1 - 1/{10}^n}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{10}^{nm}}
\end{align}

(The last expression above is itself quite amusing, since the coefficient of $1/{10}^k$ is the number of distinct ways of writing $k$ as a product of two positive integers.)

*Analytically*, Mathematica evaluates this sum as
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{\ln(10/9) - \psi_{1/10}(1)}{\ln(10)}\, ,
\end{equation}
where $\psi_q(z)$ is the [Q-Polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). This is *not* really a nice, tidy, closed-form solution. Now, I can *accept* that this sum may not have such a nice, tidy sum, but something about it *feels* like it should have one. (Non-rigorous, I know!) Furthermore, I'm aware that Mathematica is by no means infallible, especially when it comes to simplification of certain expressions.

So I'm wondering if a neater solution exists.

Comment: Wolfram returns the same result. Perhaps if you find a closed form for $\psi_{\frac{1}{10}}(1)$, if that is even possible, then you can have your nice closed-form solution. But I doubt such a closed form exists for $\psi_{\frac{1}{10}}(1)$.

Comment: If you write decimal expansions of the terms (e.g., $\frac19 = .1111111...$; or $\frac1{99} = .010101...$), you can see that the sum is equal to $\sum_1^\infty \frac{d(n)}{10^n}$ where $d(n)$ is the divisor counting function.

Comment: @paw88789 That is already stated by the OP in the question.

Comment: As was foreseeable, this type of series [has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Series_relations) and this is about all what one can say. (Why the avalanche of upvotes?)

Comment: The smallest number with more than $9$ divisors is $48=2^4\cdot3^1$, so the first 46 digits of the sum are simply the number of divisors of the digit position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given series is an irrational number (probably a trascendental number, too) and for its numerical evaluation it is possible to exploit some tailor-made acceleration techniques (like the one outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978329/44121) for the base-$2$ analogue). Besides that, I am not aware of any *nice* closed form for $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{d(n)}{10^n}$.

Comment: Is there a quick way to see why it *has* to be irrational?

Comment: @JohnBarber: its decimal expansion is highly aperiodic!