# Summation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n+1}$

Tags: limits, summation, exponential-function

So I was was messing around with infinite series and I came across one that is deceptively similar to the familiar $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 1 $ Simply add $1$ to each denominator of each term of the series. This is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n+1} \approx 0.76449...$ I have used all my weaponry on trying to crack it and the best I've come up with is the equivalent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n-1} $ Could somebody help me retrieve some sort of compact value for this expression ( e.g. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} $ can be rewritten as $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$) or is this pretty much impossible? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978310/find-sum-k-1-infty-frac12k1-1

Comment: If you know a closed form for $\,\displaystyle f(x):=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\,$ (I assume one cannot find one) you can use $\,\displaystyle \left(\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)\right)|_{x=1}\,$ to get a "compact value" .

Answer (score 3):

There is no known closed form for this sum.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: None known by me, anyway... But I'm pretty sure this has come up before.

Comment: @ThomKiwi Using wolfram alpha, the result is $-1+\frac{\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{i \pi}{\log(2)}\right)}{\log(2)}$. So i doubt that it has a nice form, like the $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that $$\frac{1}{2^n+1}+\frac{1}{2^n(2^n+1)} = \frac{1}{2^n},$$ and then attempt to find a closed form for the following sum, which appears to be equally difficult,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n(2^n+1)}$$ 
and then subtract the closed form of the previous sum from $1.$